# AVFoundation video file support

Tags: video, avfoundation, compatibility

Is there any requirement for a video file to be supported by AVFoundation?

If the file opens in QuickTime, is it enough? In my first AVFoundation test it seems that some file never open with AVFoundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to use *libvlc* from http://videolan.org which support much more file than *AVFoundation/QuickTime* video engine.